# Changing Values in a Series

Tags: python, pandas, logistic-regression

I need to make some adjustments to a series.  I have the following:

```
y.value_counts()

-1.0    775
 1.0    718
 0.0     32
Name: return_sign, dtype: int64
```

I want to make all the `0s = 1` and I want the `-1 = 0`.

So I would end up with 750 (1s) and 775 (-1s).

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
y = y.apply(lambda val : 1.0 if val >= 0 else 0)
```